# How to create sequences out of a dataframe and put them in an array of arrays or a list?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, dataframe

For the input of:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,  "A"],[2, "A"],[3, "B"],[4, "C"],[5, "D" ],[6, "A" ],[7, "B" ],[8, "A" ],[9, "C" ],[10, "D" ],[11,"A" ],
                           [12,  "A"],[13, "B"],[14, "B"],[15, "D" ],[16, "A" ],[17, "B" ],[18, "A" ],[19, "C" ],[20, "D" ],[21,"A" ],
                           [22,  "A"],[23, "A"],[24, "C"],[25, "D" ],[26, "A" ],[27, "C" ],[28, "A" ],[29, "C" ],[30, "D" ] ]),
                            columns=['No.',  'Value'])
```

I get the output of:

```
    No. Value
0   1   A
1   2   A
2   3   B
3   4   C
4   5   D
5   6   A
6   7   B
7   8   A
8   9   C
9   10  D
10  11  A
11  12  A
12  13  B
13  14  B
14  15  D
15  16  A
16  17  B
17  18  A
18  19  C
19  20  D
20  21  A
21  22  A
22  23  A
23  24  C
24  25  D
25  26  A
26  27  C
27  28  A
28  29  C
29  30  D
```

Now i want to create sequences of the data. That sequence defines a region of values till value "D" appears. For example in the first sequence there are the rows from No.1 till No.5(included)
The second sequence is from No.6 till No.10(included) and so on.

After that i want to code the values into numbers: A -> 1, B->2, C->3, D->4
If in a sequence the value A is followed by another A or many A's it will be summarized to one number 1. The same applies for the other values too.

First sequence = A,A,B,C,D 
For that i want to have something like that = [1,2,3,4]

For the whole output i want something like that:

```
result = list([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,1,3,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,1,3,4],[1,3,4],[1,3,1,3,4]])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 1, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 4],
 [1, 2, 1, 3, 4],
 [1, 3, 4],
 [1, 3, 1, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
from itertools import groupby
values = df['Value'].replace({'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3, 'D':4}).values
idx_list = [idx + 1 for idx, val in enumerate(values) if val == 4]
result = [values[i: j] for i, j in zip([0] + idx_list, idx_list + ([len(values)] if idx_list[-1] != len(values) else []))]
result = [[values[0] for values in groupby(l)] for l in result]
print(result)

[[1, 2, 3, 4], 
 [1, 2, 1, 3, 4], 
 [1, 2, 4], 
 [1, 2, 1, 3, 4], 
 [1, 3, 4], 
 [1, 3, 1, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: I got the error: 
NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: Any idea how to visualize the output properly?

Comment: It is expressing an order of values per sequence. 
For example in the first sequence the order is 1,2,3,4. So as bar chart it could be shown as blue,red,green and orange. The second sequence is 1,2,1,3,4. So this could be shown as bars in the colors and order blue, red, blue, green, orange.

Comment: you could also plot a line for every list of the list. otherwise, i dont really know how to visualise those values, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Here I'm using [`cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to give all elements in the same sequence a "Sequence ID" (the value goes up by 1 every time a "D" is encountered)

Then use [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group by sequence, and output each group to a list, which is in turn getting filtered so consecutive values are unified, like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby
from pprint import pprint

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,  "A"],[2, "A"],[3, "B"],[4, "C"],[5, "D" ],[6, "A" ],[7, "B" ],[8, "A" ],[9, "C" ],[10, "D" ],[11,"A" ],
                           [12,  "A"],[13, "B"],[14, "B"],[15, "D" ],[16, "A" ],[17, "B" ],[18, "A" ],[19, "C" ],[20, "D" ],[21,"A" ],
                           [22,  "A"],[23, "A"],[24, "C"],[25, "D" ],[26, "A" ],[27, "C" ],[28, "A" ],[29, "C" ],[30, "D" ] ]),
                            columns=['No.',  'Value'])

df["NumVal"] = df["Value"].map({"A":1,"B":2,"C":3,"D":4})
df["SequenceID"] = (df["Value"].shift(1) == "D").cumsum()

result = [[nums[0] for nums in groupby(g["NumVal"].tolist())] for k,g in df.groupby("SequenceID")]

pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 1, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 4],
 [1, 2, 1, 3, 4],
 [1, 3, 4],
 [1, 3, 1, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Any idea how to visualize the output properly?

Comment: The code dosen't work for other data in the dataframe. It will still give the same output?

Comment: @ML-ME what do you mean? what kind of other data?